# Tool for deploying changed files to production web server

Tags: svn, deployment

My system is based on LAMP stack. I have 2 synchronized application servers. What is the best way to deploy changed files to my both production servers.

The current scenario is:

- Sometimes I use my staging server and sometimes if its not required I directly copy files from development server to Production servers.
- I may hot fix some issue directly to my production servers.
- We use svn for development server and testing server but its not used for production server because of security concerns. I am not even sure on commits by the developers.
- Every time I have to see the differences between files and then copy the changes to my production servers. Sometimes, I have to merge the files.

Can I have some tool which can notify me that there is a change in given file in production server and then merge/copy the conflicts accordingly and deploy all changed files safely in optimized way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably start by having a mirror of directory on the deployment server stored locally where it can be version controlled. Using a mirror tool like [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) can ensure that you have the same files in both places.

Then you can have the exact things that you have on the deployment server added to subversion as well. If they do not fit the development/testing version you could have a branch for the deployment version where you do regular merges from the main branch.

This way checking for modifications becomes doing a "svn status" or "check for modifications" on the deployment mirror with your favourite svn tool where you then can check in changes easily.

Things that need to be played back into the development/testing stage obviously need to be merged back from your deployment branch into the main branch.

Comment: Thanks @centic for answering. Currently my dev server and test server are mirrored. I have some config files also which I dont want to deploy to my prod servers. If I add prod servers also in the repository, how can I block those files to my prod servers?

Comment: i would remove them on the separate branch for deployment and exclude them from merges later on, as you use separate branches, you can keep such differences on them while still able to merge other changes successfully in both directions